# Importing Django 2.0 utility functions (vs. django 1.1)

Tags: python, django

I'm upgrading my application from Django 1.11 to Django 2.0.

I understand from the documentation on utility functions in [v.2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/):

`from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` needs to change to `from django.urls import reverse`

But does this also apply to importing `resolve`? For example, should `from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve` be changed to from `django.urls import resolve`?

Comment: Django 1.1 or Django 1.11?

Comment: Yes, the article to which you link is named `django.urls` utility functions, so these functions all reside in the `django.urls` module.

Comment: yes, 1.11, I just fixed the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Django-2.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0) specify:

> - The **`django.core.urlresolvers` module is removed** in favor of its new location, `django.urls`.

So yes, all the functions that originally resided in the `django.core.urlresolvers` now are located in the `django.urls` module.

The page you link to is named [**`django.urls`** utility functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/), so all the documented functions are part of the `django.urls` module.

In case you migrate, I advise to read the [release-notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.0/). Especially the [*Backwards incompatible changes in 2.0* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-2-0) is useful, since it tells what changes you have to make to migrate your project to the next Django version.